# ViewModelBuilder generics casting issue

Tags: c#, .net, generics, casting

Wracking my brain around this to no avail, wonder if anyone can be of help?

Getting a really frustrating casting issue that im sure will have a quick answer, but is probably just happening due to my limited understanding of generic type inference or something.

Thanks in advance!

Scenario is a number of "Step" ViewModels for a Wizard site. I'm creating Builder classes for each, and using a factory to grab the specific builder for the step that gets posted back to me, which is a Collection of IStepViewModel's.

```
public interface IStepViewModelBuilderFactory
{
    IStepModelBuilder<T> Create<T>(T stepViewModel) where T : IStepViewModel;
    void Release<T>(IStepModelBuilder<T> stepViewModelBuilder) where T : IStepViewModel;
}

public interface IStepViewModel
{
}

public interface IStepModelBuilder<TStepViewModel> : IModelBuilder<TStepViewModel> where TStepViewModel : IStepViewModel
{
}

public class SpecificViewModelBuilder : IStepModelBuilder<SpecificStepViewModel>
{
}

public class SpecificStepViewModel: StepViewModel
{
}

public abstract class StepViewModel : IStepViewModel
{
}
```

The failing test!

```
[Test]
public void TestResolution()
{
    var factory = this.container.Resolve<IStepViewModelBuilderFactory>();

    IStepViewModel viewModel = new SpecificStepViewModel();

    var builder = factory.Create(viewModel); // Here

    Assert.That(builder, Is.Not.Null);
}
```

The problem!

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'Company.Namespace.SpecificViewModelBuilder ' to type
>   'Company.Namespace.Builders.IStepModelBuilder`1[Company.Namespace.IStepViewModel]'.

Factory Impl as follows using Castle.Windsor

```
public class StepViewModelSelector : DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector
{        
    protected override Type GetComponentType(System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, object[] arguments)
    {
        var arg = arguments[0].GetType();
        var specType = typeof(IModelBuilder<>).MakeGenericType(arg);
        return specType;
    }
}
```

Registration of this:

```
container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

     ....

    container
        .Register(
            Classes
                .FromAssemblyContaining<StepViewModelSelector>()
                .BasedOn<StepViewModelSelector>());

    container
        .Register(
            Component
                .For<IStepViewModelBuilderFactory>()
                .AsFactory(c => c.SelectedWith<StepViewModelSelector>()));
```

Stacktrace:

> System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2147467262   Message=Unable to cast object of type
>   'Company.Namespace.SpecificViewModelBuilder' to type
>   'Company.Namespace.IStepModelBuilder`1[Company.Namespace.IStepViewModel]'.
>   Source=DynamicProxyGenAssembly2   StackTrace:
>          at Castle.Proxies.IStepViewModelBuilderFactoryProxy.Create[T](T stepViewModel)
>          at Tests.Infrastructure.ViewModelBuilderFactoryTests.TestResolution() in
>   c:\Project\Infrastructure\ViewModelBuilderFactoryTests.cs:line 61
>   InnerException:

EDIT: `IModelBuilder<T>` interface

```
public interface IModelBuilder<TViewModel>
{
    TViewModel Build();
    TViewModel Rebuild(TViewModel model);
}
```

Comment: Looks like the error happens inside the implementation of the Create method of that factory. could you provide it please?

Comment: I'm just using the Typed factory impl of Castle.Windsor - ill add in the filter selector im using.

Comment: ok please add the .ToString() dump of the exception if you can. I'd like to see the stack trace

Comment: I've never used Castle Windsor, but I did notice in your code `IStepModelBuilder<TStepViewModel>`. Is that really supposed to be `TStepViewModel`?

Comment: @AdiLester Thanks I had seen that question - not sure how it relates to this specifically, or at least I cant derive a fix for this from that, any help there?

Comment: @Steve Thanks - Im using TStepViewModel to pass the type through to the underlying interface. As far as I know Windows needs a typed interface in order to make that selection from the pool. I may be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one interface which you are not showing here, which is the `IModelBuilder<T>` interface, but it's the key interface to solving your problem.

I'm assuming it's currently defined like this

```
public interface IModelBuilder<T> { }
```

If you use generic covariance, which is available since .NET 4, you'll be able to solve your problem by defining your interface like this:

```
public interface IModelBuilder<out T> { }
```

The `out` modifier makes your interface covariant, which will allow you to cast from `IStepModelBuilder<SpecificStepViewModel>` to `IStepModelBuilder<IStepViewModel>`. You should note that this also puts a constraint on your interface which won't allow it to define any methods with `T` as a parameter, but only as a return value.

You can read more about [Covariance and Contravariance here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx).

**EDIT**

As you mentioned in your comment, your interface probably looks something like this:

```
public interface IModelBuilder<T>
{
    T Create(T myViewModel);
}
```

If instead of passing `T` as a parameter to `Create`, it's OK for you to pass `IStepViewModel` or anything other than `T` instead, then this should solve your problem:

```
public interface IModelBuilder<out T>
{
    T Create(IStepViewModel myViewModel);
}
```

If not, then your attempted cast really shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: I have seen this also, I'll add the interface in, but I dont think I am able to use covariance with this as im using the type as an input parameter also and thus as far as i know it needs to be invariant?

Comment: Thanks for that - really useful. So as this is the case - is there any way of restructuring this whole thing to enable what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Ah i see - well you're a hero because this works, and i'll have to lump passing in a non specific type into the parameter and casting it out within! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following two definitions are not compatibile

```
public interface IStepViewModelBuilderFactory
{
    IStepModelBuilder<T> Create<T>(T stepViewModel) where T : IStepViewModel;
    //... rest of the class definition
}

public class SpecificViewModelBuilder : IStepModelBuilder<SpecificStepViewModel>
{
}
```

When the Create runs, it casts the produced type (that is `SpecificViewModelBuilder`) to his return value, that is `IStepModelBuilder<T>`.

This cannot be done, you can test it by trying to do this manually:

```
class MyTest<T> where T : IStepViewModel
    {
        void Test()
        {
            IStepModelBuilder<T> cannotImplicitlyCast = new SpecificStepViewModelBuilder();
        }
    }
```

**Edit: some (probably not so good) ideas**

This can be done:

> ```
> public class ViewModelBuilder<T> : IStepModelBuilder<T> where T : IStepViewModel
> {
> }
>
> class MyTest<T> where T : IStepViewModel
> {
>     void Test()
>     {
>         IStepModelBuilder<T> ok= new ViewModelBuilder<T>();
>         IStepModelBuilder<SpecificStepViewModel> alsoOk = new ViewModelBuilder<SpecificStepViewModel>();
>     }
> }
> ```

so you could specialize the factories, one for each SpecificStepViewModel

Comment: I agree - do you have any suggestions on how to solve this issue? Either I've been looking at this too long or its beyond me!

Comment: Interesting idea - I may come back to this at a later date. Perhaps some kind of abstract factoy could be wrapped around this to serve up the right specific factory... Thanks regardless!